# I need some assistance with string's in .h file's

Tags: c++, string

I have tried compiling this with every way I could find and nothing works!
whenever i try to compile it whether i use namespace std or #include  or anything else i dug up when trying to solve this
If anyone could help I would greatly appreciate it:

Here is the main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include Pen.h

using namespace std;


int main()
{


    Pen FavoritePen;

    FavoritePen Inkcolor = blue;
    FavoritePen Shellcolor = grey;
    FavoritePen Capcolor = blue;
    FavoritePen Style = ballpoint;
    FavoritePen length = 5.5;
    FavoritePen Brand = "Office Depot";
    FavoritePen InkLevelPercent = 30;

    //and here we will discribe our least favorite pen!

    Pen WorstPen

    WorstPen Inkcolor = red;
    WorstPen Shellcolor = red;
    WorstPen Capcolor = black;
    WorstPen Style = fountain_pen;
    WorstPen length = 5.0;
    WorstPen Brand = "Parker"
    WorstPen InkLevelPercent = 60;

    cout<<"This is my favorite Pen"<<endl;
    cout<<"Color: " << FavoritePen Inkcolor <<endl;
    cout<<"Brand: " << FavoritePen Brand <<endl;
    cout<<"Ink Level: " << FavoritePen InkLevelPercent;

    FavoritePen.write_on_paper("Hello I am a pen");
    cout << "Ink Level: " << FavoritePen.InkLevelPercent << % <<endl;



    return 0;
}
```

here is the .h of the class file:

```
#ifndef PEN_H
#define PEN_H

#include<string>

using namespace std;



     enum Color
    {
        blue,
        red,
        black,
        clear,
        grey
    };

    enum PenStyle
    {
    ballpoint,
    felt_tip,
    fountain_pen
    };

    class Pen
    {
    public:
        Color InkColor;
        Color ShellColor;
        Color CapColor;
        PenStyle Style;
        float Length;
        string Brand;
        int InkLevelPercent;

        void write_on_paper (string words)
        {
            if (InkLevelPercent <= 0)
            {
                cout<<"Oops! Out Of Ink!"<<endl;
            }
            else
        {
            cout << words << endl;
            InkLevelPercent = InkLevelPercent - words.length();
        }
    }
        void break_in_half()
        {
            InkLevelPercent = InkLevelPercent - words.length();
            Length = Length / 2.0;
        }
        void run_out_of_ink()
        {
            InkLevelPercent = 0;
        }
      };

#endif // PEN_H




edit: Here is the error log

||=== Build: Debug in Book 1, Chapter 8 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
 Chapter 8\main.cpp|2|error: #include expects "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>|
 Chapter 8\Pen.h||In member function 'void Pen::write_on_paper(std::__cxx11::string)':|
 Chapter 8\Pen.h|40|error: 'cout' was not declared in this scope|
 Chapter 8\Pen.h|40|error: 'endl' was not declared in this scope|
 Chapter 8\Pen.h|44|error: 'cout' was not declared in this scope|
 Chapter 8\Pen.h|44|error: 'endl' was not declared in this scope|
 Chapter 8\Pen.h||In member function 'void Pen::break_in_half()':|
 Chapter 8\Pen.h|50|error: 'words' was not declared in this scope|
 Chapter 8\Pen.cpp|6|error: definition of implicitly-declared 'Pen::Pen()'|
 Chapter 8\Pen.cpp|11|error: definition of implicitly-declared 'Pen::~Pen()'|
 Chapter 8\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
 Chapter 8\main.cpp|22|error: 'Pen' was not declared in this scope|
 Chapter 8\main.cpp|24|error: 'FavoritePen' was not declared in this scope|
 Chapter 8\main.cpp|25|error: expected ';' before 'Shellcolor'|
 Chapter 8\main.cpp|26|error: expected ';' before 'Capcolor'|
 Chapter 8\main.cpp|27|error: expected ';' before 'Style'|
 Chapter 8\main.cpp|28|error: expected ';' before 'length'|
 Chapter 8\main.cpp|29|error: expected ';' before 'Brand'|
 Chapter 8\main.cpp|30|error: expected ';' before 'InkLevelPercent'|
 Chapter 8\main.cpp|34|error: expected ';' before 'WorstPen'|
 Chapter 8\main.cpp|37|error: 'WorstPen' was not declared in this scope|
 Chapter 8\main.cpp|38|error: expected ';' before 'Capcolor'|
 Chapter 8\main.cpp|39|error: expected ';' before 'Style'|
 Chapter 8\main.cpp|40|error: expected ';' before 'length'|
 Chapter 8\main.cpp|41|error: expected ';' before 'Brand'|
 Chapter 8\main.cpp|53|error: expected primary-expression before '%' token|
 Chapter 8\main.cpp|53|error: expected primary-expression before '<<' token|
||=== Build failed: 24 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the error with you ? i can help but just be clear a little

Comment: I spot lots of things that could be causing compilation errors.  Please post the exact error messages you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

Change your second line of main.cpp to this:

`#include "Pen.h"`

For `#include "filename"` the preprocessor searches first in the same directory as the file containing the directive. This method is normally used to include programmer-defined header files.

and you have to use constructors if you want to define a new object and you can't define object members like this. Don't forget that C++ is a case-sensitive language.

your main.cpp code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Pen.h" // added quotation marks
// using namespace std;  // a bad habit, though not a cause of failure
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()

{
    Pen FavoritePen(blue,grey,blue,ballpoint,5.5,"Office Depot",30);
    //and here we will discribe our least favorite pen!
    Pen WorstPen(red,red,black,fountain_pen,5.0,"Parker",60);
    cout<<"This is my favorite Pen"<<endl;
    cout<<"Color: " << FavoritePen.InkColor <<endl;
    cout<<"Brand: " << FavoritePen.Brand <<endl;
    cout<<"Ink Level: " << FavoritePen.InkLevelPercent<<endl;
    FavoritePen.write_on_paper("Hello I am a pen");
    cout <<endl<< "Ink Level: " << FavoritePen.InkLevelPercent << "%" <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and your Pen.h:

```
#ifndef PEN_H
#define PEN_H

#include <string>

enum Color 
{
    blue,
    red,
    black,
    clear,
    grey
};

enum PenStyle
{
    ballpoint,
    felt_tip,
    fountain_pen
};

class Pen
{
public:
    Color InkColor;
    Color ShellColor;
    Color CapColor;
    PenStyle Style;
    float Length;
    string Brand;
    int InkLevelPercent;

    Pen(Color fav, Color shell, Color cap, PenStyle style, float lng, string brand, int level) : // using a field initializer list
         InkColor(fav),
         ShellColor(shell),
         CapColor(cap),
         Style(style),
         Length(lng),
         Brand(brand),
         InkLevelPercent(level) { }

    void write_on_paper (string words)
    {
        if (InkLevelPercent <= 0)
        {
            std::cout<<"Oops! Out Of Ink!"<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << words << std::endl;
            InkLevelPercent = InkLevelPercent - words.length();
        }
    }

    void break_in_half(string words)
    {
        InkLevelPercent = InkLevelPercent - words.length();
        Length = Length / 2.0;
    }

    void run_out_of_ink()
    {
        InkLevelPercent = 0;
    }
};

#endif // PEN_H
```

Answer (score 0):

You failed to include the header that defines `string`, despite using `string` in a way that requires its definition. To solve the problem, include the header that defines `string` before using `string`.

Comment: That's the problem I am having with it, when i include the : #include <string>
or:
#include 'string'
It just says that it then can't figure out the headers inclusion in main.cpp

Comment: there I included the error log in the post if that will help!